# Why the permission location alert doesn't appear?

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, android-permissions

I'm trying to show a location permission alert on my react native android app, but doesn't appear.

this is my code, firstly the function called to check permission:

```
checkPermission = async cb => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            title: "IZI CHECK",
            message: translate("access_location_msg")
          }
        );
        console.log("granted:", granted);
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          cb();
        } else {
          alert(translate("location_permission_denied"));
        }
        console.log("Granted:", granted);
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    } else {
      cb();
    }
  };
```

finally, I do a call into **componentdidmount()**:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.checkPermission(() => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position)=>{
            this.fetchProfileStatus(position);
          },
          error => {
            if (error.code) {
              console.log(error)
              this.props.navigation.goBack();
            }
          },
          Platform.OS === 'android' ? {} :{enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 }
        );
      });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: But when I'm using [https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation] and I change navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() to Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() the message alert appears and works well.

Comment: I want to use navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()  instead of  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(), how can I fix that ?